# How can I implement chart with range slider in js, preferably React-friendly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, data-visualization

i did this kind of [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ySgS.png) with Google-Charts and now I wanted to know if there is a (easy) way do to this with another library ? Preferably a "React-friendly" library. It would be better if this is a free-to-use library and it will be gold if it is open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Try devextreme-react. This lib has paid solutions, but for the stuff you are looking for, I think free options will be enough. https://www.npmjs.com/package/devextreme-react

example: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/PointsAggregationFinancialChart/React/Light/

Comment: Yea, good lib but i would prefer some full free solutions, thanks anyway